# What do you call a set of wooden tubes hanging from a ceiling?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call this? I have no words to describe it. But what you need to know is these tubes are hollow, and when struck by the "clapper", for a lack of a better word, they make gentle sounds

[image]

Comment: To answer the implied question, yes I'd call the middle piece a "clapper", because it performs the same function as the clapper in a bell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they were hanging outside, the wind would move them and they would make gentle sounds. In that instance, one would call these wind chimes.

In an interior space, I would call them simply chimes.

Comment: This is in fact a ***wind chime***, which is supposed to be hung outdoors, usually from an overhang on a porch or from a tree branch. But this one happens to be hung indoors. There's no special word to describe one hung from a ceiling.

Comment: The original poster referenced 'a clapper'. They are chimes to be sure, but if there was an expectation they would be struck by a clapper in their current use, the 'wind' portion may not apply, though I'm sure if it was hung outside, it would behave as a wind chime. In any event, they are chimes.

Comment: I'm familiar with this exact model. Do an image search for "wooden wind chime". There's a flat piece of wood suspended from the black string that that hangs from the "clapper", and the wind blows it so it strikes the tubes. Just because someone has hung it indoors doesn't change what it is.

Comment: Ah, okay, fair enough!

Comment: If your house is draughty enough, wind chimes work perfectly fine indoors too!  :)